# Open/arrange ALL InfoWindows on a Google Map (any API version)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my spare time, I help out with a neighborhood group that takes part in tree plantings a few times a year.  I've created and printed geocoded google maps of our planting locations which are very helpful for the various teams doing the plantings.

One thing I can't seem to accomplish is to get the map to show ALL infowindows open simultaneously.  I'd like to be able to show the species of tree at the planting site, rather than making people look at the marker label and find that on a separate list.  On a large monitor, I'm able to zoom in enough that overlapping infowindows isn't a (huge) problem.  I haven't seen any indications that google has any code in there for automatic arranging, but if there is, even better.

All of the posts I can find are related to infowindows not closing properly when another is clicked, or that the content isn't properly updating for each marker, but nobody seems to have asked about this type of usage scenario.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Maps API V3, you can do it easily.

Usually, when you want the info window to open on a click, you create an event to handle that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

in this case, you want to also just open the infowindow:

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Do this after you create each infowindow and marker.

For readability, you might consider using a label on the marker instead, say using MarkerWithLabel utility library:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/